# Pointer formatting in C++

Tags: c++

I know this is probably on here somewhere, but I can't find it. I only get pointer to pointer answers. So I'm doing a study guide (honestly, not cheating. If you think otherwise, please feel free not to answer). Anyways when looking through my notes, I can't find a simple and concise answer to this as his explanations are all over the map, and he mixes his notes with C formatting. Here's the question:

Given the following function prototype:

```
 void vec_sum(vec_t &v1, vec_t v2, vec_t *v3);
```

Assuming the objective is to put the sum of the first two in v3, which is the correct approach?

```
A. v3.x = v1->x + v2.x; 
B. v3->x = v1.x + v2.x; 
C. v3->x = v1->x + v2.x; 
D. None of the above
```

Any help would be great. If you have a link that answers this question, that would also be awesome. I'd rather have a link and find out on my own than have the answer just given to me.

Comment: Try it and see. The wrong answers will produce compile-time errors…

Comment: (want to test code quickly? Try an online tool like this one: http://codepad.org/)

Comment: Thanks guys. 

And Dave dammit thanks for that. I'm an idiot for not thinking of that first. I'll post the correct answer for anyone else who needs this maybe down the line.

Comment: @Dave while "trial and error" is perfectly valid for some homework, it might get tricky during some exams. :) So it's still better trying to solve the task on paper, then using a computer to verify you're right. If you're wrong, try to find the reason (even if it's with the help of a compiler).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there's the brute-force way to solve this: Just write a simple program trying all your possible solutions.

Second, you can solve this analytically and it's rather easy to be done. Consider what data types `v1`, `v2`, and `v3` are and write down how you'd have to access them.

`v1`:

> `v1` is a reference. The elements can therefore be accessed using `.`.

`v2`:

> `v2` is a variable (copy). So the elements can once again be accessed using `.`.

`v3`:

> `v3` is a pointer and needs a dereference to be accessed. As such you'll need `->` (or `*` and `.`) to access elements.

With that knowledge you can determine the possible solutions not following these simple rules:

> **A** assumes that `v1` is a pointer, which is wrong. **B** follows the conditions set above, so it's the solution. **C** once again assumes that `v1` is a pointer. Since **B** applies, **D** isn't the solution either.

Answer (score 0):

Answering in the spirit of the question I'd recommend

- Google for the difference between C++ references and
  pointers and their syntax.
- Then a search on the difference between
- call by value
- call by reference

Comment: Call by value and call by reference don't really matter in this context. It's all about accessing members and dereferencing.

Answer (score -1):

Note `vec_t` is actually a reserved identifier and it probably should not be defined in user space code.

But lets forget that

```
v3:   Is a pointer (thus elements are accessed via ->)

v1:   Is a reference to an object to type vec_t
v2:   Is an object of type vec_t

Sinve v1/v2 act like objects there members would usally be accessed by .
```

If vec_t is a struct with a member x then it will act exactly as described above. If `vec_t` is some exotic type then you may need to do some digging (C++ the type information is the most important information so without it things are just guess work).

But if we assume:

```
struct vect_t
{
     SomeType x;
};
```

- You can discard (A) because V3 is a pointer (thus you need -> to access its members)
- You can discard (C) because V1 is a reference (thus you use . to access its members unless it vec_t is a typedef to a pointer)
- I would guess (B)